# Positioning in ConstraintLayout causes HorizontalScrollView to cut off content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, horizontalscrollview, android-constraintlayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/object_detailed_information_bar"
        android:padding="@dimen/object_detailed_information_bar_padding">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/object_type_icon_image_view"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/restaurant_marker_icon"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/object_name_text_view_margin_start_or_left"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/object_name_text_view_margin_start_or_left"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/object_type_icon_image_view">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/object_name_text_view"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:lines="1" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I positioned the TextView wrapped by ScrollHorizontalView to be the right of the ImageView using `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/object_type_icon_image_view"`. But it caused also unexcepted behaviour. Text stored in TextView can be scrolled but it's cut off by few letters. When i delete this line `app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/object_type_icon_image_view"`, text it's fully shown while scrolling. Is there any way to fix that issue?

**Screens:**

```
android:text="123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"
```

1. Before scroll when positioned to the right of ImageView
   [image: Before scroll]
2. After scroll when positioned to the right of ImageView - it's cut off
   [image]
3. Before scroll without positioning
   [image]
4. After scroll without positioning - it's ok
   [image]

Comment: explain with a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Change the width of your `HorizontalScrollView` to 0dp and constrain its right-hand edge to the parent:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

**Explanation:**

Right now, your `HorizontalScrollView` is using `wrap_content` for its width. This makes it attempt to be as long as the text, but the parent (the `ConstraintLayout`) won't allow its children to have a width larger than itself. So your `HorizontalScrollView` winds up being the same width as the `ConstraintLayout`.

However, you've *positioned* the `HorizontalScrollView` such that it has been moved slightly to the right. This means that there's part of the view that is invisible; the `ConstraintLayout` is clipping the `HorizontalScrollView`.

To fix this, you need to make sure that the `HorizontalScrollView` is as wide as the space between the right edge of the image and the right edge of the parent. You already have a left constraint on the `HorizontalScrollView`, so you need to add a right constraint. Once both sides are constrained, you can use a width of 0dp to mean "match constraints"; now the `HorizontalScrollView` will size itself to the available space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/object_type_icon_image_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@color/link_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/object_type_icon_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/object_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Horizontal Scroll View"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you need this?

[image]

Comment: added some screens